# React Input field validation - avoid request by pressing enter; test failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I need to disable a submit button if input validation fails. Two issues.

It is a custom validation for React component `<Input>`. Currently, this code works *almost* well -- If validation fails, confirm button is not clickable = good! But pressing enter/return, the incorrect value can still be sent out = bad. How could I avoid the request being sent by pressing enter/return?

The second issue is, the code fails with the automated tests. The test expects a certain `km` value, but instead receives `0` (which is the `initialState`). Manually tested, then always a correct value is sent out to backend. So, is my code wrong, or rather is the test incorrect?

(Just starting with programming & React)

Code sections are as follows:

**orderStatus.js**

```
useEffect(() => {
setKm(order.stayStill?.km || 0);
const isKmValid = Number.isInteger(Number(km)) && Number(km) > 0;
if (approachingDest) {
    if (!isKmValid) {
        setErrorMessage(gettext('Value must be integer!'));
    } else {
        setErrorMessage(null);
    }
    setDisableConfirmButton(!isKmValid);
    setKm(km);
} else {
    setModalOpen(false);
    setSendingRequest(false);
}
}, [order, approachingDestination, km]);

return (
<div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
    ...
    <ConfirmModal
        onConfirm={nextStatusHandle}
        modalIsOpen={isModalOpen}
        onModalCancel={() => setModalOpen(false)}
        disableConfirmButton={disableConfirmButton}
    >
        {approachingDest && (
            <>
                <Input
                    id="km"
                    label={gettext('Km given')}
                    type="number"
                    value={km}
                    onChange={e => setKm(e.target.value)}
                />
                <span className="error-message">{error.errors?.km_given || errorMessage}</span>
            </>
        )}
    </ConfirmModal>
</div>
);
```

**ConfirmModal.js**

```
<button
disabled={disableConfirmButton}
onClick={onConfirmClick}
type="button"
>
{gettext('Confirm')}
</button>
```

**Test.js**

```
it('should ask for Km before changing to `in destination`', async () => {
const orderApproachingDest = {
    ...order,
    status: 'Approaching destination',
    statusCode: OrderStatusCodes.approachingDest,
};
const { getByText, getByLabelText } = renderStatus(
    {
        isMgr: true,
        cId: 1000,
    },
    orderApproachingDest,
);

fireEvent.click(getByText('Next status').closest('button'));
const kmInput = await waitFor(() => getByLabelText('Km provided by the driver'));

expect(parseInt(kmInput.value, 10)).toEqual(order.stayStill.km);
});
```

Comment: Try adding `onKeydown = {e => { if(e.key === "Enter"){ e.preventDefault() } } }` to the input.

Comment: Thank you, but sadly this has no effect. Enter still sends the request out when it shouldn't. If I replace the `e.preventDefault()` with `alert()`, then pressing enter gives me the alert. I also noticed if I'm not in the input field, and press enter, the modal closes, and a request is sent out. So I guess the `preventDefault()` should go somewhere else?

Comment: Try the same on the `form` element with the `onSubmit` handler...

Comment: There is no `form` used. The only way I've found to affect it is to change something in `<ConfirmModal onConfirm={nextStatusHandle}>`. Tried your code (in many variations), but unsuccessfully.

Comment: mmm.. Can't tell. But re-try all your *variations* with both `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` and its close friend `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`... Maybe. Beyond that, I don't know.